# Send Reminder via outlook

Tags: outlook

We have a set of processes that need to be performed. Some are done daily, some weekly and some monthly. There is a deadline set up for each process before which it should be completed. We need to send a reminder to the team in the following way.

1. If the process runs daily and needs to be completed before a particular time, then a reminder should be sent 2 hours before that
2. If it runs weekly on a particular day then a reminder should be sent at 10AM IST of that particular day
3. If the process runs monthly and needs to be completed before a particular day, then a reminder should be sent just a day before the end date.

How can I create a VB script for the above task?

Answer (score 0):

The Reminder class doesn't provide any property or method for changing the time. But you may create an appointment item on your calendar for each event (it can be a recurrent item) and set the reminder for the item. The [ReminderMinutesBeforeStart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869379(v=office.15).aspx) property of the AppointmentItem class returns an integer indicating the number of minutes the reminder should occur prior to the start of the appointment. The [ReminderSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff865300.aspx) property allows to set a Boolean value that is True if a reminder has been set for this item. For example:

```
Sub AddAppointment() 
 Dim apti As Outlook.AppointmentItem  
 Set apti = Application.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)   
 apti.Subject = "Car Servicing"  
 apti.Start = DateAdd("n", 16, Now)  
 apti.End = DateAdd("n", 60, apti.Start)  
 apti.ReminderSet = True  
 apti.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 60  
 apti.Save  
End Sub
```